# Disappearing footnote when the titlesec package loaded

Tags: footnotes, titlesec

I want to write some footnotes in headings. When I using the `titlesec` package, first footnotes are hidden.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\textheight}{2cm}

\begin{document}
    
    \paragraph*{First\footnote{First} second\footnote{Second}}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/43 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pair `\footnotemark\footnotetext{…}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength{\textheight}{2cm}

\begin{document}

    \paragraph*{First\footnotemark\footnotetext{First} second\footnotemark\footnotetext{Second}}

\end{document}
```

[image]